# ObservableCollection convert to EntityQuery?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services, observablecollection

Is it possible to cast/convert `ObservableCollection`  to `EntityQuery` ?

```
if (sender is InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>)
{
    ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy> divisions =
               new ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy>((sender as InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>).Value);

    this.Load(query.ApplyTo(divisions), 
          lo => { callback(this.CreateResult(lo)); }, state); // Error
}
```

This method `query.ApplyTo` accepts only EntityQuery....

Comment: You should make your InvokeOperation return an EntityQuery, otherwise I don't see how you could do this conversion.